# Vertex operator - state mapping in Polchinski's book

Tags: operators, hilbert-space, string-theory, conformal-field-theory, vacuum

In Polchinski's textbook String Theory, section 2.8, the author argues that the unit operator $1$ corresponds to the vacuum state, and $\partial X^\mu$ is holomorphic inside couture $Q$ in figure 2.6(b), so operators $\alpha_m^\mu$ with $m\ge0$ vanishes.

I am a bit confused about why $\partial X^\mu$ has no pole inside the contour. Before this section $\partial X^\mu$ always has the singularity part ($1/z^m$). Therefore would it be possible for you to give a more mathematical argument what condition requires $\partial X^\mu$ having no poles in this case?

Answer (score 4):

The main point is that the [operator](http://www.physics.thetangentbundle.net/wiki/Conformal_field_theory/state-operator_correspondence)-[state](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/state-field+correspondence) correspondence maps all the annihilation operators to zero, so that an operator-valued Laurent series in $z$ and $\bar{z}$ maps to a ket-state-valued power series in $z$ and $\bar{z}$.

Answer (score 1):

Start with the action (2.1.1), where the fields $\partial X^{\mu}$ are defined on a given world sheet. Then eq. (2.1.12) tells you that $\partial X^{\mu}$ is holomorphic on this surface.

The way we can develop a holomorphic function depends on the topology on the surface on which it is defined. If it is the complex plane (the usual case), then you have an expansion $\sum\limits_{m \geq 0} a_m z^m$. If you are on the Riemann sphere, you add a condition at infinity, and the only holomorphic functions (valued in the complex plane) are the constants. Now if you go on a cylinder, as is the case for the propagation of a free string, then you relax a condition at the origin, and the expansion is $\sum\limits_{m \in \mathbb{Z}} a_m z^m$. Even if this has "poles", it is indeed a holomorphic function on the cylinder, or the plane without the origin.

Now in the state-operator correspondence, if you insert the identity operator at the origin, it reduces to going from the cylinder to the plane. There is no more hole at the origin, since now in picture 2.6.b the contour can cross the $\mathcal{A}$ insertion. So the coefficients with negative $m$ in $\sum\limits_{m \in \mathbb{Z}} a_m z^m$ must annihilate the corresponding state. This identifies this state with the ground state.

Answer (score 1):

Before we put a local operator at the origin of the $z$ plane, the origin is actually a singularity of the exponential map that sends the cylinder to the complex plane. So, the local operators are singular at the origin before the state-operator correspondence.

The state-operator correspondence is the observation that if we substitute the singularity at the origin with a local operator there, then we can map states at $t=\pm\infty$ on the cylinder to local operators at the origin of the plane.

The singular behavior at the origin is determined by the local operator that you put at the origin. The $1$ local operator is characterized by not having a singularity at all. Other states/operators like $:\partial X^{\mu}\bar{\partial}X^{\nu}e^{ikX}:$ reproduce a singularity at the origin.

Answer (score 1):

I will give yet a different, simpler,  answer. All of these discussions are operator equations. Now as an operator equation $\bar{\partial}\partial X^\mu = \text{contact terms}$, see the discussion on p 35. But contact terms would arise from any operators inside the contour. The only such operator is the unit operator, and so there are no contact terms and $\bar{\partial}\partial X^\mu =0$ and so $\partial X^\mu$ is holomorphic.

Answer (score 1):

How about just using the 1st equation of (2.6.15)
for $\ Q=\alpha^\mu_m\ (m\geq0)\ $ and $\ \mathcal A =1$ ?
$$
0=[\alpha^\mu_m\,,1]\propto{\rm Res}_{\,z\to0}\,z^m\partial X^\mu1.
$$

Anyway, the definitions of $\ [\mathcal Q, \mathcal A]\ $ and initial state $\ | \mathcal A\,\rangle\ $  for an operator $\ \mathcal A\ $ at the origin should be clear. I reached my conclusion. Just using the 1st equation of (2.6.15), we can define for any $\mathcal A$ at the origin

$$
|\mathcal A\,\rangle\cong\mathcal A\qquad Q|\mathcal A\,\rangle\cong[Q,\mathcal A]\ \left(=\mathrm{Res}_{\,z\to0}\ j(z)\mathcal A\quad
{\rm If}\ \ Q=\oint j\,\frac{dz}{2\pi i}\ \right).
$$

I guess it’s a consistent way, try Jacobi id etc … .

Still, in Fig.2.6 in Joe’s book “contour $Q$” confused me at first, why didn’t he use $C$ instead?

And, what are concluded from this? $\ $From (2.7.1) we have

(i) $\ \,1a^\mu_m=0$ for any $m\ \ $ ( there is nothing “inside” the origin ),

(ii) $\ \,a^\mu_m1 =0\ (m\geq0)\ \ $ ($\ \mathcal A=1\,$ behaves like a projection “outside” the origin ).

So, Joe is simply saying that let’s accept the existence of the ground state $|1\rangle$.

After that, Joe is frequently using $\ \partial^mX^\mu(0)\ $ which is defined by

$\ a^\mu_{-m}|1\rangle\cong 
[a^\mu_{-m},1]= a^\mu_{-m}1=a^\mu_{-m}(0)\,,\, $ namely
$\ \partial^mX^\mu(0)=\partial^mX^\mu1|_{z=0}\ $

(we cannot substitute $=0$ for $\partial^mX^\mu(z)$ without “$1$”) ,

and taking $\ \mathcal AQ=0\ $ in the same view as (i) so that $\ [Q,\mathcal A]=Q\mathcal A\,$.

Comment: The point of my answer is that ‘caurse $\partial X^\mu$ is holomorphic in the “operator meaning”, please see (2.1.17). So only $z^m$ part of my formula contributes to $1$ for $\mathrm{Res}_{z\to0}$.

Answer (score 1):

When we write that
\begin{equation}
\partial X^\mu(z) = -i \sqrt{ \frac{\alpha^\prime}{2} } \sum_{m=-\infty}^\infty \frac{\alpha^\mu_m}{z^{m+1}},
\end{equation}
we must always remember that this a solution to the equations of motion. In canonical quantization, you promote this object to an operator and work in terms of the modes $\alpha^\mu_n$, acting with the raising ones on the vacuum to create initial and final states for scattering. If you choose to instead work in terms of path integrals, which is where vertex operators come in, you compute correlators by integrating over all possible functions $X^\mu(z,\bar{z})$, which therefore do not have the general form written above. So the manipulations used to derive the state-operator correspondence assume a path integral over them (see section 4.6 of Tong's notes on string theory for a very clear explanation of this). Therefore, for the identity to be the vertex operator of the vacuum state, what must be zero is
\begin{equation}
\Omega=
\int \mathcal{D} X e^{-S} \oint \frac{dz}{2 \pi i} z^m \partial X^\mu(z,\bar{z})
\end{equation}
for $m \geq 0$, and similarly for the antiholomorphic field. Note that I wrote $\partial X^\mu(z,\bar{z})$ instead of the usual $\partial X^\mu(z)$ to emphasize the fact that this $\partial X^\mu$ is not required to solve the equations of motion.

With this, the question becomes how to show that the above object vanishes, given that path integrals are not restricted to run only over holomorphic functions. This will be proven below (I have N. Berkovits to thank for this proof).

Integrating the Polyakov action by parts, the object we wish to show is zero takes the form
\begin{equation}
\Omega = \int \mathcal{D} X \exp{ \left(\frac{1}{2 \pi \alpha^\prime} \int d^2z \, X \partial \bar{\partial} X   \right) } \oint_{\partial C} \frac{dz}{2 \pi i} z^m \partial X,
\end{equation}
where we will choose for the contour $\partial C$ a circle around the origin of radius $R$. Since the action is free, we can treat each component $X^\mu$ separately, so the Lorentz indices will be omitted. Using the divergence theorem in the complex plane (equation (2.1.9) of Polchinski volume 1), we can rewrite the contour integral as
\begin{equation}
\oint_{\partial C} \frac{dz}{2 \pi i} z^m \partial X = \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_C d^2z \, z^m\,\partial \bar{\partial} X = \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int d^2z \, z^m\,\partial \bar{\partial} X \, \Theta(R^2 - |z|^2),
\end{equation}
where the last integral is over the entire complex plane and $\Theta$ is the Heaviside theta function. This leads to
\begin{align}
\Omega &= \int \mathcal{D} X \exp{ \left(\frac{1}{2 \pi \alpha^\prime} \int d^2z \, X \partial \bar{\partial} X   \right) } \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int d^2z \, z^m\,\partial \bar{\partial} X \, \Theta(R^2 - |z|^2) \\
&= \frac{d}{da}\bigg|_{a=0} \mathcal{D} X \exp{ \left\{  \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int d^2z \, \left(  \frac{1}{\alpha^\prime} X \partial \bar{\partial} X + a z^m \partial \bar{\partial} X \Theta(R^2 - |z|^2)  \right)   \right\} }.
\end{align}
Now, do a change of variables
\begin{equation}
X \to X^\prime = X + \frac{a \alpha^\prime}{2} z^m\Theta(R^2 - |z|^2).
\end{equation}
The integral becomes
\begin{align}
&\int d^2z \, \left(  \frac{1}{\alpha^\prime} X^\prime \partial \bar{\partial} X^\prime - \frac{a}{2} X^\prime \partial \bar{\partial} \left( z^m \Theta(R^2 - |z|^2) \right) - \frac{a}{2}  z^m \Theta(R^2 - |z|^2) \partial \bar{\partial} X^\prime  + a z^m \partial \bar{\partial} X^\prime \Theta(R^2 - |z|^2) + \mathcal{O}(a^2) \right) \\
&= \int d^2z \,   \frac{1}{\alpha^\prime} X^\prime \partial \bar{\partial} X^\prime + \mathcal{O}(a^2),
\end{align}
where integration by parts was used to go from the first to the second line. Since $\mathcal{D}X = \mathcal{D}X^\prime$, we have
\begin{equation}
\Omega = \frac{d}{da}\bigg|_{a=0} \mathcal{D} X^\prime \exp{ \left( \frac{1}{2 \pi \alpha^\prime} \int d^2z X^\prime \partial \bar{\partial} X^\prime \right) + \mathcal{O}(a^2)} =0.
\end{equation}